# Can knockout.js mapping plugin ignore computed observable properties added to properties of the viewModel?

Tags: javascript, plugins, knockout.js, mapping

I have inherited some code that uses the knockout mapping plugin and am trying to fix bugs, one of which is that viewModels must be updated, rather than replaced, when a Web page is re-visited during a session. I have studied http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html and imagine that I understand the relevant parts, at least how to create and use the ignore array, for example:

```
var mapping = {
    'ignore': ["propertyToIgnore", "alsoIgnoreThis"]
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

In my case, to update the viewModels, I actually need to use this parameter list:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, viewModel);
```

My problem is that the code does some post-processing on the viewModel after it is initially loaded, creating computed observables on elements of arrays - one of which is named "showRemove" for example. Although I created an ignore array that contains "showRemove", as in:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { "ignore": ["showRemove"] }, viewModel);
```

... the fromJS call throws an exception with the message '"showRemove" is undefined.'

Is there a way to get the plugin to ignore properties added to the viewModel that are not at the top level of the hierarchical structure of the object? I would think there would have to be, but I cannot easily find an explanation of how to do it.

I intend to get this to work even if I have to manually write detailed update code, but I would really prefer not to have to do that.

I think the question and its background are clear, but if not, let me know and I will supply more detail, including possibly a (non-)working code example.

Comment: I managed to get the debug version of the mapping plugin JS code and will debug it to find my answer. Meanwhile, anyone who happens to know the answer is welcome to save me some time.

Comment: After working with this problem for two days, I concluded that it represents a bug in either ko.mapping or the base knockout.js library. I developed a "workaround," which was to just not do what I was trying to do, because it was deemed non-essential. My next task, should I deem it worth the effort, will be to create a small demo project that produces the error and hand it over to the knockout developers.

Comment: Did you try to declare the computed observable after the mapping?